# How to get all the numbers surrounding a particular number?

Tags: matrices

I have a 2d array of numbers.
And I would like to know: how to get all the numbers surrounding a particular number.

Here is one 2d array of numbers with 5 rows and 4 columns:

[image]

So for number 0, I would like to get the numbers that surround him:

```
0: 1,5,4
For number 1:
1: 2,6,5,4,0
2: 3,7,6,5,1
3: 7,6,2
4: 0,1,5,9,8
5: 0,1,2,6,10,9,8,4
6: 1,2,3,7,11,10,9,5
7: 2,3,11,10,6
8: 4,5,9,13,12
9: 4,5,6,10,14,13,12,8
10: 5,6,7,11,15,14,13,9
11: 6,7,15,14,10
12: 8,9,13,17,16
13: 8,9,10,14,18,17,16,12
14: 9,10,11,15,19,18,17,13
15: 10,11,19,18,14
16: 12,13,17
17: 12,13,14,18,16
18: 13,14,15,19,17
19: 14,15,18
```

Can some sort of universal formula be defined that would enable me getting all the surrounding numbers of the particular number in the 2d array?

The upper 2d array is just an example. In reality I might have hundreds of rows and hundreds of columns.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: I think more context is needed. What do you want to do with these numbers? Are you trying to program a computer to do this? At the moment this isn't really a maths problem...

Comment: Yes, it will eventually be a script. But I do not need help with a script, with a mathematical formula. I actually didn't know that this in essence is not a mathematical problem.

Comment: @MorganRogers what more context do you need?

Comment: Hint: do an if statement for when the chosen number is internal or when it is on the left or right boundary of the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no direct mathematical expression per se, that will give you the result you want, at least not the kind you would expect.

However, if you really want to write the surrounding integers as a set and define it mathematically, this is how I would personally go at it:

First, lets say your matrix is of dimensions $M\times N$.

For each integer $n$, the corresponding row $L$ can be calculated as $L(n) = \left\lfloor\cfrac{n}{N}\right\rfloor+1$.

Let $\mathcal{L_k}$ be the set of integers $n$ such that $L(n)=k$.

Then for each integer $n$ of the matrix, the set $S_n$ of surrounding integers is defined by:

$$
S_n=\left(\left(\{(n-N-1),(n-N),(n-N+1)\}\cap\mathcal{L}_{L(n)-1}\right)\cup\left(\{(n-1),(n+1)\}\cap\mathcal{L}_{L(n)}\right)\cup\left(\{(n+N-1),(n+N),(n+N+1)\}\cap\mathcal{L}_{L(n)+1}\right)\right)\cap[0,N\times M-1]
$$

It seems daunting but as a script it's very easy to implement using array mappings and filters for example. Or simple `if` statements.

---

Basically to implement it:

1. you take the first set $\left\{(n−N−1),(n−N),(n−N+1)\right\}$ and you only keep those whose row is the row of $n$ minus 1.
2. Then take the second set $\left\{(n−1),(n+1)\right\}$ and only keep those whose row is the same as $n$.
3. Do the same for the last set $\left\{(n+N−1),(n+N),(n+N+1)\right\}$ and only keep those whose row is the row of $n$ plus 1.
4. And finally, filter all the integer that are not within the range $[0,N\times M-1]$.

Calculating the row is as easy as getting `floor(n/N)+1`. The syntax depending on the language used for your script of course.

Take 19 for example. The 3 sets are:

- $\{(19-4-1),(19-4),(19-4+1)\}=\{14,15,16\}$
- $\{(19-1),(19+1)\}=\{18,20\}$
- $\{(19+4-1),(19+4),(19+4+1)\}=\{22,23,24\}$

Calculate the row for each:

- $\{L(14),L(15),L(16)\}=\{4,4,5\}$
- $\{L(18),L(20)\}=\{5,6\}$
- $\{L(22),L(23),L(24)\}=\{6,6,7\}$

So here, since the row of 19 is $L(19)=5$, then you only keep from each set, respectively: $\{14,15\}$,$\{18\}$ and $\{22,23\}$.

Put together, that's $\{14,15,18,22,23\}$

Now the last step is checking the global accepted range. Here, $N=4$ and $M=5$ so the range is $[0,N\times M-1]=[0,19]$. Which means you end up with $\{14,15,18\}$

In javascript for example:

```
[n-N-1,n-N,n-N+1].filter((i) => L(i) === L(n) - 1)

.concat([n-1,n+1].filter((i) => L(i) === L(n)))

.concat([n+N-1,n+N,n+N+1].filter((i) => L(i) === L(n) + 1))

.filter((i) => i >= 0 && i <= N*M-1 )
```

The `concat` represents the $\cup$ (union of sets) and the `filter` represents the $\cap$ (intersection of sets) in the mathematic expression of the set above.

Of course you need to define L,N, and M:

```
var N = 4, M = 5;
function L(n) { return Math.floor(n/N)+1 };
```

Comment: Thank you Dolma.
But this highly exceeds my mathematical knowledge, and I do not know how to implement it as a script.

Comment: @Bernard I edited the answer and added a quick explanation for the implementation

Comment: Thank you Dolma! But I am not sure I am following.
Let's say I picked number 14. It's in the 4th row.There are 5 rows. So floor(14/5-1) = 1?

Comment: No, $N$ is the number of columns (in your example $N=4$). So the row of 14 is indeed the 4th: $L(14)=floor(14/4)+1=3+1=4$

Comment: Oh yeah, just realised I made a little typo in the last sentence (it's +1 not -1), i'll edit it.

Comment: Thank you Dolma. But how can I calculate the row of the number 14? The L(n) formula you provided is for columns.

Comment: No, it takes into account the number of columns only because it is the only thing impacting the row of the integer but it's indeed meant to calculate the row, not the column. The formula for the column would be something like $C(n)=n\%N+1$

Comment: I added an example at the end of the answer.

Comment: @Bernard also added an example of script (javascript). You can adapt it to any other language if necessary.

Comment: Hi Dolma. This is brilliant!!! I do not know how to express my gratitude. Thank you very much!!!